# Am I using word-embeddings correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

**Core question : Right way(s) of using word-embeddings to represent text ?**

I am building sentiment classification application for tweets. Classify tweets as - negative, neutral and positive.
I am doing this using Keras on top of theano and using word-embeddings (google's word2vec or Stanfords GloVe).

To represent tweet text I have done as follows:

1. used a pre-trained model (such as word2vec-twitter model) [**M**] to map words to their embeddings.
2. Use the words in the text to query **M** to get corresponding vectors. So if the tweet (**T**) is "Hello world" and **M** gives vectors **V1** and **V2** for the words 'Hello' and 'World'.
3. The tweet **T** can then be represented (**V**) as either **V1**+**V2** (add vectors) or **V1V2** (concatinate vectors)[These are 2 different strategies] [Concatenation means juxtaposition, so if **V1, V2** are d-dimension vectors, in my example **T** is 2d dimension vector]
4. Then, the tweet **T** is represented by vector **V**.

If I follow the above, then My Dataset is nothing but vectors (which are sum or concatenation of word vectors depending on which strategy I use). 
I am training a deepnet such as FFN, LSTM on this dataset. But my results arent coming out to be great.

Is this the right way to use word-embeddings to represent text ? What are the other better ways ?

Your feedback/critique will be of immense help.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03820) paper by Zhang and Wallace which investigates use of convolutional neural nets combined with word embeddings to classify sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, for your purpose, it is better to think about another way of composing those vectors. The literature on word embeddings contains examples of criticisms to these kinds of composition (I will edit the answer with the correct references as soon as I find them).

I would suggest you to consider also other possible approaches, for instance:

- Using the single word vectors as input to your net (I do not know your architecture, but the LSTM is recurrent so it can deal with sequences of words).
- Using a full paragraph embedding (i.e. https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf)

Comment: when you say use single word vectors as input to your net I feed V1 followed by v2 but the label is for whole sentence. How is this any different from concatenating V1 V2 ?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean with concatenating. Look at this: http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/. If what you mean is using V1 in place of x_(t-1) and V2 in place of x_t, this is the correct way of doing this (and only RNN as LSTM allow this).

Comment: Paragraph embeddings from what I've seen don't work well with short pieces of text like tweets.

Comment: @Lemm Ras: By concatenation I meant juxtaposition, so if **V1, V2** are d-dimension vectors, in my example **T** is 2d dimension vector

Comment: @viksit: Can you kindly point to some writeup(s)/analysis if any that lead  to the conclusion you mentioned

Comment: @AnujGupta The tweet T however could have a different number of words, let's say n: how do you deal with the unknown n*d dimensional vector? And what is the input dimension of your net?

Comment: @Lemm Ras: I take a fixed length (this could be max, min or avg of all tweets in dataset) and then left pad those whose length is smaller than the decided length

Comment: @AnujGupta One problem could be caused by that padding/cutting. What I mean is that if you cut using min or avg, there is a contextual information that does not pass through to the net if T-dim>min or avg. For the max instead, most of the time, the d-dimensional inputs around the max value are never used. If they are almost never used, they are almost never updated and this means no convergence and a possible source of noise.

Comment: Not off the top of my head - mostly through empirical evidence. You should read the paper and those that cite it. One main issue is that to get a good set of embeddings, you need a *large* amount of data so that sparsity isn't an issue. That scale is generally hard to get.

Comment: @LemmRas: I have used Max in my experiments. Your explanation certainly makes lot of sense. Thats why I am not trying LSTMs to take advantage of sequential data without getting suffering from the curse of many leading zeros (left padding). Thank you so much for your time

Comment: @viksit: which paper are you referring to ?

Answer (score 0):

Summing them doesn't make any sense to be honest, because on summing them you get another vector which i don't think represents the semantics of "Hello World" or may be it does but it won't surely hold true for longer sentences in general

Instead it would be better to feed them as sequence as in that way it at least preserves sequence in meaningful way which seems to fit more to your problem.

e.g A hates apple Vs Apple hates A this difference would be captured when you feed them as sequence into RNN but their summation will be same.
I hope you get my point!